# Algorithm for combinations of integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am having difficulties for writing an algorithm that will create an array of arrays, from a single array of integers.

Say, I have an

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
```

What I need from it is an array of an arrays that will look like this:

```
int[][] array = new int[][]{

    {-1,2,3,4,5},

    {1,-2,3,4,5},

    {1,2,-3,4,5},

    {1,2,3,-4,5},

    {1,2,3,4,-5};
```

Thank you in advance!!

EDIT:
The following code works for the case if I want to have only one negative value. How about if I would like to have 2,3,4... negative values? Is there a way to make it more dynamic? For example, from `{1,2,3,4,5};` to get: `{-1,-2,3,4,5}, {-1,2,-3,4,5}, {-1,2,3,-4,5}, {-1,2,3,4,-5}, {1,-‌​2,-3,4,5},{1,-2,3,-4‌​,5}, {1,-2,3,4,-5}`...‌​. or for 3 negative values: `{-1,-2,-3,4,5}, {-1,-2,3,-4,5}, {-1,-2,3,4,-5}, {1,-2,-3,-4,5},‌ ​{1,-2,-3,4,-5}, {1,2,‌​-3,-4,-5}`...etc I hope you get my point! Thanks again guys!!

Comment: So a for loop and a bit of work on the diagonal? Make a method that takes in your array and go from there

Comment: The following code works for the case if I want to have only one negative value.

How about if I would like to have 2,3,4... negative values?
Is there a way to make it more dynamic?

For example, from 
`{1,2,3,4,5};`
to get:
`{-1,-2,3,4,5},{-1,2,-3,4,5},{-1,2,3,-4,5},{-1,2,3,4,-5},{1,-2,-3,4,5},{1,-2,3,-4,5},{1,-2,3,4,-5}`....

or for 3 negative values:
`{-1,-2,-3,4,5},{-1,-2,3,-4,5},{-1,-2,3,4,-5},{1,-2,-3,-4,5},{1,-2,-3,4,-5},{1,2,-3,-4,-5}`...etc
I hope you get my point!

Thanks again guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
    int l = intArray.length;
    int[][] newArray = new int[l][l];

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            newArray[i][j] = j == i ? intArray[j] * -1 : intArray[j];
        }
    }
```

`newArray` will have the values you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
public class x
{
    public static int[][] convert(int in[])
    {
        int s = in.length;
        int out[][] = new int[s][s];

        for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) {   // row loop
            for (int j = 0; j < s; ++j) {
                if (i == j)
                    out[i][j] = -in[j];
                else
                    out[i][j] = in[i];
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    public static void print(int in[][])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; ++i) {
            String sep = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < in[i].length; ++j) {
                System.out.print(sep + in[i][j]);
                sep = ", ";
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        int in[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int out[][];

        out = convert(in);
        print(out);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] intArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    int algoIntArray[][] = new int[intArray.length][intArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < algoIntArray[i].length; j++){
            if (i == j){
                algoIntArray[i][j] = -intArray[j];
            } else {
                algoIntArray[i][j] = intArray[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will work for you!